# Service bus queue in e-commerce application

Tags: sql-server, signalr, azureservicebus

We have an e-commerce application running on MS SQL.

Every now and then we have a flash sale, and once we start inserting all the orders into the database, our site's performance drops.  We have it at the point where we can insert about 1,500 orders in a minute, but the site hangs for a few minutes after that.  The site only hangs once the inserts start happening.

I have been looking into using Azure Service Bus queues mixed with SignalR to manage the order process, as this was suggested to me a while back.  The way I see it happening is (broad overview):

1. Client calls a procedure on the server which inserts an order into a queue.
2. Client gets notified that they are in a queue.
3. We have a worker process which processes the order from the queue and inserts it into the database.
4. Server then notifies the client that the order is processed and moves them onto the payment page.

I am new to SignalR and queues in general so my questions are:

1. Will queues actually have a performance benefit.  If so, why?
2. Are queues even the correct thing to use in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overview you mention makes sense. It seems like you should be able to do it without SignalR since ServiceBus will let you know once it successfully inserted the message into the queue.

It is not that queues give you better performance for 1 request. Messages placed onto the queue will be stored until you are ready to process them. By doing this you will not suffer "peak" issues and you will be able to receive from the Queue at a speed that you know your system is able to sustain (Maybe 500 orders/minute or whatever number works for you).

So they will give you a much more stable latency per request without bringing down your system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking along the same lines in terms of performance. Just one question, if I did not use SignalR how would I notify the clients browser once the message has actually been processed?